# How can you make an emacs macro wait for cscope query results?

Tags: emacs, macros, elisp, ctags, cscope

I am trying to write a macro which calls `cscope-find-functions-calling-this-function` on each and every tag in a file displayed in the `*Tags List*` buffer (created by `list-tags` command). **This should create a buffer which contains list of all functions calling a set of functions defined in a certain file.**

I just position the point at the start of the first tag in the *Tags List* buffer and then run the following keyboard macro to do this. This is the sequence of keystrokes in the keyboard-macro:

```
1.  <f11>              ;; cscope-find-functions-calling-this-function                                                                                                           
2.  RET                ;; newline      [shows results of cscope in a split window]
3.  C-x C-p            ;; mark-page
4.  C-x C-x            ;; icicle-exchange-point-and-mark
5.  <up>               ;; previous-line
6.  <end>              ;; end-of-line             [region to copy has been marked]
7.  <f7>               ;; append-results-to-buffer
8.  C-x ESC O          ;;                 [move back to split window on the right]
9.  C-x b              ;; icicle-buffer        [Switch back to *Tags List* buffer]
10. *Tags              ;; self-insert-command * 5
11. SPC                ;; self-insert-command
12. List*              ;; self-insert-command * 5
13. RET                ;; newline
14 . <down>            ;; next-line       [Position point on next tag in the list]
```

**Problem:** 
I get no results in the buffer, and I found out that's because Step 3-7 execute even before
cscope prints the results of query made on Steps 1-2.

*I can insert a pause in the macro by using C-x q, but I'd rather like the macro to wait after Step 2, until cscope has returned with the results and then continue further automatically. I suspect this is not possible through a macro, maybe a LISP function... I'm not a lisp expert myself. Can someone please help? Thanks!*

---

Details:

- I have [Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) installed so by
  default I get word at point in current buffer as input in minibuffer.
- F11 is bound to
  `cscope-find-functions-calling-this-function`
- [windmove](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WindMove) is installed and C-x <right> (C-x ESC o - as shown below) takes you to the
  right window.
- F7 is bound to
  `append-results-to-buffer` which is
  defined as:

```
(defun append-results-to-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (append-to-buffer (get-buffer-create "c1") (point) (mark)))
```

This function just appends the currently marked region to a buffer named "c1".

Answer (score 2):

The CEDET Suite has cscope support in cedet-cscope.el which calls to cscope synchronously.  You can probably borrow something from there to use from your keyboard macro.

Alternately, you could use CEDET's symref tool (semantic-symref-symbol) to do the heavy lifting on top of CScope.  It can also use GNU Global, or IDUtils.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Eric! I guess I need to do some digging around. Good thing is I'm loving this whole LISP business.